# Destructured array aliasing for nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to rename some objects from one array (eventFetch) and pass them into another (mapEvents). I'm trying destructuring aliases to do this, but I'm trying to rename a nested object so I don't think this is the right approach.

Here's an example of the eventFetch array:

```
 "events": [
        {
            "name": {
                "text": Event Name, 
                "html": null
            }, 
            "description": {
                "text": null, 
                "html": null
            }, 
            "id": "23412412", 
            "url": "https://www.eventbrite.com.au/e/eventname", 
            "start": {
                "timezone": "Australia/Sydney", 
                "local": "2016-05-28T19:00:00", 
                "utc": "2016-05-28T09:00:00Z"
            }, 
            "end": {
                "timezone": "Australia/Sydney", 
                "local": "2016-05-28T22:00:00", 
                "utc": "2016-05-28T12:00:00Z"
            },
```

And the destructure I'm trying:

```
const mapEvents = eventFetch.map(({ name: title, start: start, end: 
end, url }) => ({ title, start, end, url }));
```

I want to rename `name.text` to title rather than just renaming `name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could destructure it in the following way:

```js
var eventMap = {
  "events": [{
    "name": {
      "text": "Event Name",
      "html": null
    },
    "description": {
      "text": null,
      "html": null
    },
    "id": "23412412",
    "url": "https://www.eventbrite.com.au/e/eventname",
    "start": {
      "timezone": "Australia/Sydney",
      "local": "2016-05-28T19:00:00",
      "utc": "2016-05-28T09:00:00Z"
    },
    "end": {
      "timezone": "Australia/Sydney",
      "local": "2016-05-28T22:00:00",
      "utc": "2016-05-28T12:00:00Z"
    }
  }]
};
const mapEvents = eventMap.events.map(({ name: {text:title, html}, start, end, url }) => ({ name:{title, html}, start, end, url }));
console.log(mapEvents);
```